# Non-parametric estimation of error distribution in regression

Tags: regression, logistic, estimation, nonparametric

Consider the following model: $y = 1$ if $g(X\beta) + u > 0$ and $y=0$ otherwise where $u$ is $iid$ according to some distribution function $F$. I want to recover the distribution $F$ without making too many assumptions. That is, I'll only assume that the distribution is *monotonic* and continuously differentiable. How to do that ???

I think a good starting point is to use a semi-parametric regression to estimate $\hat\beta$ and get the index $X\hat\beta$. Then I can use non-parametric regression between $y$ and $X\hat\beta$ to compute some kind of residuals and use them to estimate $\hat F$.But I don't know how to do it in practice.

Comment: Why do you need F? Otherwise it's a probit model.

Comment: I don't want to assume a particular distribution (probit model if I am not wrong uses a Gaussian) and I need $F$ because I want to simulate a new batch of data under the true $F$.

Comment: Did you consider Gibbs sampling under probit? I don't think it's possible to recover the distribution of errors from binary dependent observations

Comment: I am not sure. @Aksakal could you please expand a bit your suggestion?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model#Gibbs_sampling)'s Wikipedia article on Gibbs sampling for probit. There's normal distribution implicit

Comment: Do you have any constraints on $g$ (e.g. is it smooth, monotonic, etc.)? If not, the problem is underdetermined because you could trivially choose any arbitrary $\beta$, then find a pathological-looking $g$ (infinitely many, in fact) that classifies all points perfectly. My gut feeling is that monotonic $g$ would make the problem easier because the decision boundary would be a single hyperplane.

Comment: Let's assume the error distribution is monotonic.

Comment: @user20160 I modified the problem statement following your advice. Do you also suggest a solution?